# Профиль из двух сущностей на FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine, fosuserbundle

Использую Symfony 2.7.4 и FOSUserBundle. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - нужно добавить дополнительную информацию, т.е. поля, в созданный профиль пользователя.

Заполнение полей происходит через форму редактирования профиля.

Все хорошо, но храниться дополнительные поля должны в отдельной таблице. 
То есть дополнительные поля содержатся не в основной сущности FOSUserBundle, а в дополнительной. Основная сущность у меня - Customer.php, дополнительная - CustomerAdress.php.

Попытался осуществить это объявлением класса второй сущности в основной таким образом:

src/MyProject/UserBundle/Entity/Customer.php:

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\CustomerAdress;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\CustomerRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstname;

    public function setFirstname($firstname) {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getFirstname() {
        return $this->firstname;
    }
    public function setAddressLine1($addressLine1)
    {
        $CustomerAddress = new CustomerAddress();
        $CustomerAddress->addressLine1 = $addressLine1;
        return $CustomerAddress;
    }
    public function getAddressLine1()
    {   
        $CustomerAddress = new CustomerAddress();
        return $CustomerAddress->addressLine1;
    }
}
```

src/MyProject/UserBundle/Entity/CustomerAdress.php:

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 *  @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\CustomerAdressRepository")
 */
class CustomerAdress
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy=«AUTO»)
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="customerId", type="integer")
 */
protected $customerId;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="addressLine1", type="string", length=255)
 */
public $addressLine1;
}
```

ProfileController.php - не изменял.

Изменения в ProfileFormType.php:

```
protected function buildUserForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
    ->add('firstName', 'text', array('label' => 'First name:', 'trim' => TRUE, 'constraints' => array(new NotBlank(), new Length(array('min' => 1, 'max' => 255)))))
    ->add('addressline1', 'text', array('label' => 'AddressLine1', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
   ;
}
```

Как уже понятно, поле «addressline1» выводится на форму, но не записывает введенное значение в таблицу CustomerAdress и не выводит текущее.

Прошу помочь с решением данного вопроса…

Также совершенно нет догадок, как связать поля ID в таблице Customer и CustomerID в CustomerAdress, а так же дальнейшие действия для обеспечения работоспособности поля «addressline1» на форме. Есть только мысль, что каким-то образом нужно изменить контроллер ProfileController.php.

Comment: Оно и не должно записываться - вы же нигде не сохраняете customer address. Вам нужно прописать `@OneToOne`-связь и отдельно сохранять customer address в entity manager, либо использовать `@Cascade`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Customer extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\CustomerAddress", mappedBy="customer", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $customerAddress;
    ............
}

class CustomerAddress
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="customerAddress", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $customer;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="address_line", type="text")
     */
    protected $addressLine;
    .......
}
```

форма CustomerAddressFormType.php:

```
    $builder->add('addressLine');
```

форма ProfileFormType.php:

```
$builder->add('customerAddress', new CustomerAddressFormType());
```

Comment: Отлично! Сущности связал по описанному принципу, и обьявил поле описанным вами способом. Но что-то все равно не так.
Форма открывается, при отсутствии связанной записи в таблице Customer_Adress поле на форме пустое. При попытке заполнения пустого поля - Ошибка - Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given.

Comment: При наличии связанной записи в таблице (строка «street 444» в adressLine1) - форма не открывается, Ошибка - The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\Customer. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\Customer" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\Customer to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.